# Scrolling Credits Screen in Batch File?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I don't really have a context here, there isn't any code that I have to go with it. I'm just wondering if anyone out there has any idea on how to have a scrolling credits screen, with basic lines and a slow and/or adjustable scroll speed. I have searched thoroughly, for quite a few days, and I have made this SO account just to ask this question. If it helps, what I'm hoping for is an extremely basic 'movie' credits screen.
Thanks in advance, Noah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty basic:

```
@echo off
for /L %%z in (1,1,55) do echo(
for %%a in (
"Director: Me"
"Producer: Him"
"Actor 1: The Dog"
"Actor 2: The Cat"
"Actor 3: The Goat"
"The end"
) do (
echo              %%~a
ping -n 2 localhost>nul
echo.
)
pause
```

Comment: I am extremely disappointed in my own abilities. Looking at your code, what I tried (which failed miserably on many occasions) was stupidly close. You are correct, it is very simple, thanks for the answer. I fear I might have given up otherwise.

Comment: `for /L %%i in (1,1,55) do echo( &ping -n 2 localhost>nul` just before the pause completes the job.

Comment: Surprisingly, I figured that line out after a minute of thinking. Thanks anyway, though, Stephan.